# putting an "ascii art" printf into a char array ?

Tags: c++, ascii-art

I have this object

```
void Game::Logo(void)
{
    printf("                 _ _ \n");
    printf("                (_|_)\n");
    printf("   __ _ ___  ___ _ _ \n");
    printf("  / _` / __|/ __| | |\n");
    printf(" | (_| \__ \ (__| | |\n");
    printf("  \__,_|___/\___|_|_|\n");
    printf("                     \n");
    printf("\n");
}
```

In order for me to create an array out of this, I have to go through each line and put a `,'',` between anything, and when the actual name I'm working with is much larger, it's going to take forever and prone to human error.

How would I create a function that could do this all for me without error, and potentially diffrent options for array size according to the size of the "logo".

would I go about storing line each into a string:

```
string row0 = "                 _ _ ";
string row1 = "                (_|_)";
string row2 = "   __ _ ___  ___ _ _ ";
string row3 = "  / _` / __|/ __| | |";
string row4 = " | (_| \__ \ (__| | |";
string row5 = "  \__,_|___/\___|_|_|";
string row6 = "                     ";
```

and then creating a function of this sort:

```
printfToArray(int numRow,int numCol, string rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++)
    {
        //create an array of char logo[numRow][numCol]
        //numCol is the number of max space require, so this case, 23 because of \n as well
        //then copy it somehow into the array within loop
    }
}

int numRow = 7; //because 7 strings
```

as these seems like the only way I can remotely think of, but even so I don't understand how I would go about doing this.

Comment: I think you are needing [this](http://www.asciiarts.net/) ?

Comment: @SCaffrey no no, I meant create an multi dimenstional array of lol with all the printf's in it.

Comment: If you have issues with escaping codes (having to type `\\` everywhere), then use raw string literals.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Because I see some of both. While that works, it's good practice to use `cout` for C++ `string`s and `printf` for C `char*`s.

Comment: Initializing a `const char *const logo[]` array should be straight-forward. Do you really need a `const char logo[][]` array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `std::vector` to put the lines in an array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vs
    {
        R"(                 _ _ )",
        R"(                (_|_))",
        R"(   __ _ ___  ___ _ _ )",
        R"(  / _` / __|/ __| | |)",
        R"( | (_| \__ \ (__| | |)",
        R"(  \__,_|___/\___|_|_|)",
        R"(                     )"
    };

    for (auto s : vs)
        std::cout << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out now

Comment: It would probably be better to omit the newlines (and the leading spaces, and the blank lines) in the data so that it could be combined with other ASCII art on the same line of output.  You'd include the newlines in the output operation instead.  But the vector of strings is undoubtedly the right way to go.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. Unless you use raw string literals (or type `\\ ` everywhere), you're inventing the `\_` escape sequence... **Edit**: Edited the post taking this into account .

Comment: Do these have a limit in size? After much playing around I got it to work and print the conents, and my lines are about 60 characters long each and there's 4 of them. It seems that everytime I try and print it's cutting them off or putting a random newline

Comment: That has nothing to do with `std::vector` The console window will only display 60 lines. In console window, click the system button on top-left, click "Default" and "Properties" increase the buffer size